# Action Name Attribute Not Linking to Correct View()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, overloading

I'm Trying to Overload an ActionResult in MVC(4) so that It can return the same view.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SearchQuery(string SearchTerm, bool isAdvanced = false)
{
    return View(new SearchViewModel(SearchTerm, 50, 0, -1, false, 0, null, isAdvanced));
}

[ActionName("BatchSearchQuery")]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SearchQuery(SearchViewModel SVM)
{
    return View(SVM);
}
```

However when I Call the BatchSearchQuery it returns an error "The view 'BatchSearchQuery' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."

Does Anybody Know How I could Return the Correct View from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the view name when rendering it:

```
[ActionName("BatchSearchQuery")]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SearchQuery(SearchViewModel SVM)
{
    return View("SearchQuery", SVM);
}
```